# How to initialize Inmemory db context in UTest Class

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

How to initialize fake inmemory database context in UnitTest class for testing repository, which using CatDbContext. I got Error: OneTimeSetUp: No suitable constructor was found.
How i need ti initialize database, to use for testing catRepository.

```
    namespace CatsCRUDAppTest
{
    public class CatRepositoryTests
    {
        private IRepository<Cat> catRepository;
        private FakeDbContext context;

        private Cat defaultCat = new Cat() {Id = 0, Name = "name" };

        // OneTimeSetUp: No suitable constructor was found
        public CatRepositoryTests(FakeDbContext fake)
        {
            catRepository = new CatRepository(fake);
            context = fake;
        }
        //

        [Test]
        public void CreateTrueTest()
        {
            Cat cat = defaultCat;
            catRepository.Create(cat);
            context.SaveChanges();

            Cat existingCat = context.Find<Cat>(cat.Id);

            Assert.IsNotNull(existingCat);
        }
    }
```

Repository class:
That class get CatDbContext to initialize.

```
    namespace DAL.Repositories
{
    public class CatRepository : IRepository<Cat>
    {
        private CatDbContext db;

        public CatRepository(CatDbContext context)
        {
            db = context;
        }
        public async void Create(Cat item)
        {
            await db.Cats.AddAsync(item);
        }
```

FakeDbContext:

```
public class FakeDbContext : CatDbContext
    {
        public FakeDbContext(DbContextOptions<CatDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Cat> Cats { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "FakePersonalSiteDbContext");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to use dbBuilder.

```
 private IRepository<Cat>? catRepository;
            private FakeDbContext? context;
    
        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            var dbBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CatDbContext>();
            dbBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "FakeDbContext");
            context = new (dbBuilder.Options);
            catRepository = new CatRepository(context);
        }
```